# How to add a variable in absolute file path using fs.writeFile( )

Tags: path, filesystems, absolute-path, writefile

```
let fd = xeleCatalog.descendantFirst('order');
let file = fd.toXmlString();
let filename = data['Testorders.ID'].toString().concat(".xml");
let path = 'E:\\IGEM\\orders\\'filename;

fs.writeFile(path,file, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Created XML file for TestOrder ID:'+ filename);
  });
```

I want the variable filename be the FILENAME of the file that is being created by writeFile()

I can directly give the filename variable to the writeFile function in place of path variable and that creates the file with required name in the same folder where the code file is, but I want this file to be created in another folder ( path given above) on the same drive
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path')    

let fd = xeleCatalog.descendantFirst('order');
let file = fd.toXmlString();

// join the folder and the new filename
let folderPath = 'E:\\IGEM\\orders\\tomV3_testXML';
let filename = data['Testorders.ID'].toString().concat(".xml");
let absolutePath = path.join(folderPath,filename)


// create the file in given folder
fs.writeFile(absolutePath,file, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Created XML file for TestOrder ID:'+ filename);
  });
```

Using path.join() function helped in achieving the desired result.